# Django not finding database object when trying to render view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm getting the following error when I go to the /val/4/13/bs url:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/val/4/13/bs
Raised by:  valapp.views.BSDetail
No balance sheet found matching the query
```

Here is the views.py code:

```
class BSDetail(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = BSDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = PostEvent.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class BSDisplay(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'valapp/balsheet.jinja'
    model = BalanceSheet


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        entityobject = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=self.kwargs['pkent'])
        context['bsinfo'] = BalanceSheet.objects.filter(company = entityobject)
        return context

class EntityDetail(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = EntityDetailDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class EntityDetailDisplay(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entity
    template_name = 'valapp/entitydetail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        engobject = get_object_or_404(Engagement, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        entobject = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=self.kwargs['pkent'])
        context['engagement'] = engobject
        context['entity'] = entobject
        return context
```

The urls.py code is:

```
app_name = 'valapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ValDetailView.as_view(), name='engagement'),
    path('<int:pk>/<int:pkent>/', views.EntityDetail.as_view(), name='entitydetail'),
    path('<int:pk>/<int:pkent>/bs', views.BSDetail.as_view(), name='bs'),
    path('newval/', views.newval, name="newval"),
    path('<int:pk>/newentity/', views.NewEntity.as_view(), name="newentity"),
]
```

Here is the models.py:

```
class BalanceSheet(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = BS_ACT_CHOICES)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=2022)
    tab_abv = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    tab_rdt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    tab_debt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

There are balance sheet objects associated with Entity 13.

It's a bit messing with the the 'pk' and the 'pkent', which I plan to clean up in the future.  Basically, each balance sheet is associated with an entity, which is associated with an engagement.

When I go to val/4/13, the page does load properly so there is an entity 13 and there are plenty of objects associated with entity 13 in the BalanceSheet model that should be loading.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, your URL structure of `<int:pk>` and `<int:pkent>` is that the first pk is your Engagement and pkent is Entity. Your `BSDisplay` view is a DetailView which has a BalanceSheet model, however the pk passed to it is an Engagement pk, which Django is unable to find. Either change the model of the view or the PK that is passed to the URL.

Comment: Hi 0sVoid.  Thank you very much for your response.  I see where I went wrong.  I need to be using a ListView rather than a DetailView because I'm trying to show many objects rather than the details of just one BalanceSheet Object.  Thank you again.